# How to filter a text output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.6

I'm trying to get some data out of a webpage and for doing this I used this:

```
import bs4
import requests

r = requests.get("URLOFTHEWEBSITE")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

hi =soup.select('tbody')
hi0 = hi[0].getText()

print(hi0)
```

From this i get as output:

```
**10 lines of nothing**

5522 
TRENTO
22:56

5

1

**10 lines of nothing**

Ferma a: PERGINE (23.01) - POVO MESIANO (23.11) - VILLAZZANO (23.15) - S.BARTOLAMEO (23.19) - S.CHIARA (23.21) - TRENTO (23.28)                                                                                                                                

*about 30 lines of nothing*
```

I need only the values from "5522" to "1", like this:

```
a = "5522"
b = "TRENTO"
c = "5"
d = "1"
```

How can i filter those values and ignore all the other text?

I tried with the `filter()` command but didn't work.

I'm new on python so if it sounds like a stupid questions I'm sorry  :| .

Comment: We need the HTML to investigate (just enough to recreate the problem).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: This is the link ( https://stazionevirtuale.rfi.it/ArriviPartenze/ArrivalsDepartures/Monitor?PlaceId=1728&Arrivals=False ) It's not the original one because values on that page change based on time. This is the original link ( https://stazionevirtuale.rfi.it/ArriviPartenze/ArrivalsDepartures/Monitor?PlaceId=2480&Arrivals=False ) but now (22:32 BST) It should return no value

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

If everything is the same format, I would try looping through and set a flag to end.

```
for line in hi0:
   if(line.contains('1')):
       #insert code here
       break #breaks you out of the loop
```